# How to retrieve data from children components in a React-ful way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an large application with nested components. Each component can be individually modified but I would like to be able to have the data persist between sessions. Currently, I am having each component be in charge of saving updates using the browsers LocalStorage but I would ultimately like to be able to export all of the app data to a single JSON file and use that to save the user's progress in the app.

My best idea, as of posting, is to use a prop to trigger a callback function passed to all the children. When a prop (which I called `msgPort` is changed) each child component will pass their data up to the parent component. So far it works as I would expect but it feels like this method is bad practice and not "React-ful". Is this method acceptable, or are there some pitfalls of scaling this method up to a much larger application? Any advice/feedback is much appreciated.

---

Here is a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/save-nested-data-s5umb?file=/src/App.js

And here is the same code from the CodeSandbox

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

function A(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    id: props.id,
    inputValue: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.msgPort) {
      props.retrieveData(props.order, data);
    }
  }, [props.msgPort]);

  return (
    <div className="m-3 text-start p-3 border row g-0">
      <div>
        <span className="float-start mb-2">Component A</span>
        <span className="float-end">ID: {props.id}</span>
      </div>

      <input
        className="form-control"
        type="text"
        placeholder="inputValue"
        value={data.inputValue}
        onChange={(evt) => {
          setData({ ...data, inputValue: evt.target.value });
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const B = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    id: props.id,
    checkedValue: true
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.msgPort) {
      props.retrieveData(props.order, data);
    }
  }, [props.msgPort]);

  return (
    <form className="m-3 text-start p-3 border row g-0">
      <div>
        <span className="float-start mb-2">Component B</span>
        <span className="float-end">ID: {props.id}</span>
      </div>

      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          className="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={data.checkedValue}
          onChange={() => {
            setData({ ...data, checkedValue: !data.checkedValue });
          }}
        />
        <label className="form-check-label">Default checkbox</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [msgPort, setMsgPort] = useState("");
  const [appData, setAppData] = useState([]);

  const saveData = () => {
    setAppData(["", "", ""]);

    setMsgPort("save"); // this will trigger the retrieve data in the children components
  };

  const retrieveData = (index, componentData) => {
    setAppData((prevState) => {
      let newData = [...prevState];
      newData[index] = componentData;

      return newData;
    });

    setMsgPort(""); // Is there a potential for a component to not get updated before this get reset
  };

  return (
    <div className="App m-2 p-3 border">
      <h1 className="h2">Children</h1>

      <div className="p-3 m-2 border bg-light">
        <A id={1} order={0} msgPort={msgPort} retrieveData={retrieveData} />
        <B id={2} order={1} msgPort={msgPort} retrieveData={retrieveData} />
        <A id={3} order={2} msgPort={msgPort} retrieveData={retrieveData} />
      </div>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-light  btn-outline-dark"
        onClick={() => {
          saveData();
        }}
      >
        Get Children Data
      </button>

      {Object.keys(appData).length > 0 && (
        <div className="my-3">
          <label className="form-label">Template Data</label>
          <span className="form-control-plaintext">
            {JSON.stringify(appData)}
          </span>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Move all your state into a single `React context, or use a Redux state, and persist state changes to localStorage and initialize from localStorage.

Comment: I currently am using localStorage to store individual component states. I ultimately want the user to be able to download a file with their data.

Comment: If you centralize your state then persisting and consuming it becomes almost trivial.

Comment: I just feel like centralizing the state is going to be a huge PITA and potentially cause a bottleneck. I'm trying to avoid having to use react-virtualized or react-window by compartmentalizing the data.

Comment: I would say passing all these callbacks as props and invocations and synchronizations would cause more of a bottleneck then just having a single state object and consumers talk to directly. That's kind of the problem the React context API and React-Redux (*built on the Context API*) exist to solve for. Maybe each component managing their own state and passing it up to their parent to "centralize" a single saved output will work.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. That way I only have to deal with one large centralized object when the user "saves" their work.

Comment: I'd suggest then to still create a context to hold the saved state value and expose out a single "saveState" callback that consumers call and pass their state when they mount or update their state. This will avoid the issue of "props drilling". If you need help with an example let me know.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps. You should turn your last comment into an answer so I can properly credit you for your work. I'd accept your last comment as an answer as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a React context to hold the state you want to "retrieve" from the children, exposing out only a single callback for them to call and pass their state up. This inverts control where the parent component doesn't need to be aware of its children and by using a React Context you don't need to drill all the state and callbacks as props through to the children. It's an opt-in system where children components need only use the `useSaveState` hook to send their state to the centralized context value.

Example:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const SaveStateContext = createContext({
  saveState: () => {}
});

const useSaveState = (key) => {
  const { saveState } = useContext(SaveStateContext);
  const saveStateWithKey = (value) => saveState(key, value);
  return { saveState: saveStateWithKey };
};

const SaveStateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    ... any side-effect with the updated states
  }, [state]);

  const saveState = (key, value) =>
    setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      [key]: value
    }));

  const value = useMemo(() => ({ saveState }), []);

  return (
    <SaveStateContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </SaveStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
const { saveState } = useSaveState(id);

const [data, setData] = useState( ... );

useEffect(() => {
  saveState(data);
}, [data, saveState]);
```

[image: Edit how-to-retrieve-data-from-children-components-in-a-react-ful-way]